# Exibir detalhe da turma

Tags: c#, vue.js

Boa tarde,

Preciso exibir os detalhes de um determinada turma, clicando em um botão, passando apenas o código. No código do Index, fiz basicamente dessa forma:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" v-b-tooltip title="Detalhes" @click="openDetalhes({ turmaId: item.turmaId })">
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

E nos methods do VUE:

```
openDetalhes: function (model) {
                this.showLoading();
                new Api('/turma/details').get(model).then(data => {
                    this.result.item = data.data;
                    this.hideLoading();
                }, (err) => {
                    this.failLoading();
                    if (err && err.data && err.data.errors) {
                        this.$eventHub.$emit('show-notidication', {
                            type: 'error',
                            title: 'Atenção',
                            text: err.data.errors[0]
                        })
                    }
                });
                //this.$router.push({ path: '/turma/details' });
            },
```

A chamada está batendo corretamente na controller, mas não está sendo exibida a página com os detalhhes.

Comment: Seu evento está soletrado corretamente? `show-notidication`, parece um erro de digitação.

Comment: realmente estava com erro de grafia, porém continua a mesma coisa

Comment: Poderia adicionar como deve ser a chamada do path da api? Seria `/turma/details/:id`? Exemplo: `/turma/details/1`?

Comment: não entendi pq a tag `c#`

Comment: apresente a sua controller